# How to Compare NSdates?

Tags: ios4, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I am new to Objective-C and need to compare `NSDate` objects I have to compare 5 days stored in an `NSMutableArray` and match them with the current date - then print them.

Answer (score 0):

This should help (with an example array of dates, stored in `dateArray`):

```
NSDate *now = {NSDate date]; // current date and time

NSArray *dateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDate dateWithString:@"2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"],
                      now,
                      [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1000],
                      [NSDate dateWithString:@"2011-03-03 18:45:32 +0600"],
                      [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1000],                          
                      nil];

for (NSDate *date in dateArray)
{
     if ([date isEqualToDate:now])
     {
         // date are equal ..
     }
     else if ([date isEarlier:now])
     {
         // date are earlier ..
     }
     else if ([date isLater:now])
     {
         // date are later ..
     }
}
```

See the `NSDate` class reference for more info. There is also a `compare:` method on two dates.

Comment: I have one query..how to add dates into an Array?